# Filter a dataframe by its entry

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

How do I filter a dataset by a specific value that can occur anywhere in the data frame and not necessarily under any one column or row ?

Suppose I have a data frame that is like this.

```
   id gender group Student_Math_1 Student_Math_2 Student_Read_1 Student_Read_2
   46      M   Red             23             45             37             56
   46      M   Red             34             36             33             78
   46      M   Red             56             63             58             NA
   62      F  Blue             59             NA             NA             68
   62      F  Blue             NA             68             87             73
   38      M   Red             78             57             NA             65
   38      M   Red             NA             75             54             NA
   17      F  Blue             74             NA             56             72
   17      F  Blue             75             61             NA             79
   17      F  Blue             NA             74             43             81
```

And I am trying to subset this data frame such that I retain all the rows and columns that contain the value `68` regardless of where it occurs within the data frame.

The final output would be

```
   id gender group Student_Math_1 Student_Math_2 Student_Read_1 Student_Read_2

   62      F  Blue             59             NA             NA             68
   62      F  Blue             NA             68             87             73
```

Any tips or suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
df = structure(list(id = c(46, 46, 46, 62, 62, 38, 38, 17, 17, 17), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Blue", "Red"
    ), class = "factor"), Student_Math_1 = c(23, 34, 56, 59, 
    NA, 78, NA, 74, 75, NA), Student_Math_2 = c(45, 36, 63, NA, 
    68, 57, 75, NA, 61, 74), Student_Read_1 = c(37, 33, 58, NA, 
    87, NA, 54, 56, NA, 43), Student_Read_2 = c(56, 78, NA, 68, 
    73, 65, NA, 72, 79, 81)), .Names = c("id", "gender", "group", 
"Student_Math_1", "Student_Math_2", "Student_Read_1", "Student_Read_2"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In general, you may consider to reshape your data structure from wide to long form. Columns 4 to 7 seem to contain all the same kind of data (grades? percentages?) while the column headers look like attributes (test name?). The wide form is often what you get when collecting data in Excel spreadsheets but the long form is often more convenient for data manipulation or aggregation in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively,

```
df[unique(which(df==68, arr.ind = T)[,1]),]

#  id gender group Student_Math_1 Student_Math_2 Student_Read_1 Student_Read_2
#5 62      F  Blue             NA             68             87             73
#4 62      F  Blue             59             NA             NA             68
```

In this case, you don't need to care about the position of the columns or where `NA`s are appeared. `unique` is used in case 68 is appeared more than once per row.

Comment: This returns duplicate rows in the instance of there being `68` more than once in a row.

Comment: @989, I found this solution simple enough and exactly what I was expecting

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
## use data from "Student_Math_1" column to "Student_Read_2" column
df[rowSums(df[4:7] == 68, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]

#  id gender group Student_Math_1 Student_Math_2 Student_Read_1 Student_Read_2
#4 62      F  Blue             59             NA             NA             68
#5 62      F  Blue             NA             68             87             73
```

Note, `df[4:7] == 68` returns a logical matrix (with `NA`), and we take `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`. During such arithmetic operation, `TRUE` is seen 1 and `FALSE` is seen 0.

---

**Follow-up**

Thanks to Ben Bolker for reminding this more readable solution, and you certainly need to grasp it, if you are learning R:

```
df[apply(df[4:7] == 68, 1L, any, na.rm = TRUE), ]
```

which applies rowwise `any` (with `na.rm = TRUE`). I can't remember where I compared these two in terms of performance. But I wouldn't bother making a quick experiment:

```
library(microbenchmark)

## For simplicity / neatness, I generate a logical matrix `X` without `NA`
X <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 2000 * 10, replace = TRUE), 2000)

## also measuring 989's solution
microbenchmark(ZL = rowSums(X) > 0,
               Ben = apply(X, 1L, any),
               "989" = unique(which(X, arr.ind = T)[,1]))

#Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#   ZL  144.24  149.76  183.3516  164.86  172.48 2077.80   100 a  
#  Ben 5610.08 5730.78 6003.0660 5779.20 5861.46 8021.72   100   c
#  989 1571.72 1639.58 2033.4224 1664.78 1721.18 5339.48   100  b
```

Comment: oops. `df[apply(df[,3:7]==68,1,any,na.rm=TRUE),]`, which isn't really much clearer than this solution.

Comment: In general I like `any()`/`all()` for readability (rather than doing numerical operations on logicals coerced to 0/1), but in this case I agree it doesn't help that much.  I think timing differences for ops like this are most often trivial unless using truly enormous data ...

Comment: @BenBolker - interesting - I thought there would be a much larger punishing time-wise. On 100k rows the difference is still only a fraction of a second. Probably ramps up substantially if 1M rows or above though.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I can only delete my comments. I have done that.